# If all the eigenvalues of $A\in M_n$ have geometric multiplicity equal to $1$, Is it true that $A=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If all the eigenvalues of $A\in M_n$ have geometric multiplicity
equal to $1$, Is it true that $A=0$?

Comment: What is the geometric multiplicity of $0$ in the zero matrix?

Comment: What about a diagonal matrix with distinct eigenvalues?

Comment: @copper.hat - What is $dim(ker(0))$?

Comment: @Undersky: Are you joking?

Comment: @copper.hat -Is it  true $dim(ker(0))=1$?

Comment: @Undersky: $\ker 0$ must be the entire space. So if $n=1$ then yes, otherwise no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Think of any matrix $A\in M_n$ with $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Then each has geometric multiplicity $1$, and the matrix is certainly not the zero matrix, as $A$ can be diagonalized so all of its eigenvalues are on the diagonal and there are zeros everywhere else, and at most one of the eigenvalues is zero.

Note also that the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ of the zero matrix is not $1$.

Comment: - Let   $A\in M_n$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Why does  each  geometric multiplicity equal $1$?

Comment: Because eigenvectors corresponding to mutually different eigenvalues are linearly independent. So, we have $n$ eigenvectors - one for each eigenvalue. And they span the whole space. There is "no room" for other eigenvectors.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp - Please more help.

Comment: Say, $n=2$. You have two eigenvalues $s$ and $t$. Let $u$ and $v$ be corresponding eigenvectors. They are linearly independent. So, they span $\mathbb R^2$. Assume there is another eigenvector $w$ corresponding to $s$. Then, since $u$ and $v$ span the space, $w = au + bv$ with numbers $a$ and $b$. But as $w-au$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $s$ (check it) and $w-au = bv$, we must have $b=0$ since $w-au$ and $v$ are linearly independent. Thus, $w= au + bv = au$. So, $w$ and $u$ are linearly dependent, meaning that the eigenspace corresponding to $s$ is only spanned by $u$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp - Thanks.